# JRebel stops to reload html resources after first "Make Project" in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 community edition

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, jrebel

I am struggling to get JRebel work properly with IntelliJ IDEA.

After application redeploy, JRebel works for html resources very well. But if I change some Java classes and use "Make Project" command to reload changes, later resources does not reload.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Can you give any code or error messages? (edit your question)

Comment: Do you have rebel.xml with classpath defined? http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html